# Lost press effect of the button when set gradient background by shape

Tags: android

Usually, there's a bit effect when we press a button. But when I set gradient background for a button by creating a shape border.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#cccccc" />
    <corners android:radius="6px" />
    <gradient
      android:startColor="#d8d8d8"
      android:endColor="#f9f2f9"
      android:angle="90" /> 
</shape>
```

and button:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/visibility"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/idle"
        android:singleLine="true"           
        android:padding="5px"
        android:textSize="14px"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"    
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:clickable="true">
    </Button>
```

the effect when press the button is lost, the button now is just like a textview, nothing is changed when I click on it.
But if I delete this line in button, everything's ok:

```
android:background="@drawable/border"
```

So any solutions to don't be lost the effect when press the button, or any solutions to make a button has border and gradient background without use shape?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for the button background, supplying different background images for each state (pressed, focused, etc.).

It will be much simpler to simply not change the button background at all.

Comment: This is described in more detail under "Button Style" in the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: Supplying different background images for each state is more than I want, I just want to the effect back when I press the button, now it's just like a textview with border

Comment: @LeoLink: Then get rid of your custom background.

Comment: sorry, I've done, it's not complex as I thought, your answer's helped me. Thanks!